# Cleaning up and extracting data from text files

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract data from non delimited text files using C#. Basically, I need to remove all unwanted character then mark the end of a line and add a line break. Once the data has been separated into individual lines I need to loop through each line in turn and extract values using Regular Expressions. I have been doing this with Perl but now need to do it using C#. The raw file contains numerous line break characters throughout the file not jut at the end of a line as you would expect. I will be able to extract values using Regex objects but I am having trouble getting the file into a format that has each record on a line of its own.

Comment: sample data would help understand what the problem is

Comment: How do you know where the line ends when it's not at any given line break and there's no delimiters?

Answer (score 0):

You provided scarce information but. This code will create you List of lines.

Note that ReadLine will take a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r") or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n").
I am not sure if this is the behaviour you expect.

```
    string fileName = "Text.txt";
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }

    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
       //can do your Regex here
    }
```

Comment: OP says that a line doesn't necesarrily ends at a line break but ReadLine reads until next line break or EOF. I suspect that OP means \n when talking about line break in which case I'm affraid your code will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The main problem is that the file contains lots of line breaks scattered throughout the text but I need to remove all of them, then find a Regex match that marks the end of the line. Once I have the data into a series of individual lines then I can use the ReadLine method to step through the file line by line applying Regex Matches. The real difficulty is getting the data separated into separate lines. I cannot supply the data as it in confidential material. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe try load whole your file into a string(StreamReader:ReadToEnd()), then use string:Remove(x) to delete unwanted line breaks/characters, then  string:Split(x) will split your string into array ( where x-delimiter).

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. I've have managed to read the entire file into a StreamReader using the ReadToEnd() method. I could remove the line breaks by the String.Remove() method. Could you please clarify how (and on what character) I could split the files into an Array? Thanks again.

Comment: You must decide on what character. This will print you ascii codes of string characters. Analyze your file(string) and see where do you want separate lines: var chArr = s.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chArr.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write((int)chArr[i]);
}

Comment: Thanks again for the advice, I think I've cracked it now. I found the string that marked the end of a line, then I split into an array with the Regex.Split() method. I can now use a foreach loop to read through the array and use Regex Matches to extract the values I need. I must say I was very impressed by the quality of advice offered as well as the response time.